# Atom.io remove uncommited changes/open files in project explorer

Tags: atom-editor

For some reason I get a open files and uncommited changes on the project explorer.

These two views don't make any sense to me (I already know what I opened by looking at the tabs, I also know what are uncommited by looking at the colors in the folder tree).

So how do I remove them from the project explorer tab? I couldn't find anything related to them in the settings. Are they plugin related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, they are plugin related; the package is called Nuclide. 
In order to remove the extra view, i followed [these](https://nuclide.io/docs/help/faq/#how-do-i-disable-most-recently-used-tab-switching) instructions from its official website.

PS: if after reloading Atom you can't access the project's files, try this: 
1. CTRL-Shift-p ("Application: Open Your Config")
2. Remove"tree-view" from disabledPackages
3. Reload editor

Good luck!

Comment: It recreates "tree-view" option after restarting? :(

Answer (score 3):

[image: "Nuclide Preferences in Atom"] Remove "Show uncommitted changes in the settings under Nuclide-file-tree